# Using Jasper ContitionalStyles with named style references

Tags: jasper-reports

I've got a situation where I create a report based on jrxml-files generated programmaitically and a style template with a given name and given style names. This works fine up to the point where there are conditional styles. Every example I found just uses ConditionalStyles to change some value like setting a different backcolor for specific situations. This can't be done here since there is no way of knowing what separates an even row style from an odd row style. Like wheter an odd row will get a gray background or an even row will get a green foreground and a black bottom pen.

What I tried or looked at:

- Using Conditional Styles - There seems to be no way of defining a style reference just to change style values
- Using a Variable for the style name - The variable didn't get evaluated
- Creating a style with 2 ConditionalStyles using even and odd styles as parent styles - these were ignored when creating the jrtx-file

So... is there a way to create alternate styled rows using style references? If yes how it is done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As there seems no solution to this, we had to change the structure of the style-files to include the conditional style instead of doing this in the document.

When walking this path and trying to change or create these style-files programmatically, be aware that in the `JRXmlTemplateWriter` that comes with Jasper, the method `toWriteConditionalStyles` is implemented as:

```
protected boolean toWriteConditionalStyles() {
    return false;
}
```

Which is unfortunate. You'll have to use your own Exporter that changes this behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Simply the way of knowing what separates an even row style from an odd row style.
**Even row** will satisfy the condition

```
(($V{REPORT_COUNT}%2) == 0)
```

**Odd row** will satisfy the condition

```
(($V{REPORT_COUNT}%2) != 0)
```

Then you can use a Conditional Styles with above conditions

Comment: This I know, what I was asking is how to reference an external named style in a conditional style or create the same result on any other way.